# Multiple Concurrent Users ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, parse-platform

Using [Parse](https://parse.com/). With the way users work on Parses backend, will I be able to write an ASP.NET MVC website that fully supports multiple concurrent users? Can multiple users access the same resources at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer is yes, Parse does allow multiple users to access the same resources at the same time. It is when multiple users try to write to the same resource at the same time where it might become tricky.